# Namedtuple greater than or less than operators giving unexpected result

Tags: python, namedtuple

When working with namedtuples, it seems there is a default "value" for the object allowing one to compare two named tuples with the `< >` operators. Can anyone explain where this value comes from or why this code returns `True`? is there a clever way to make the `>` operator compare the age without using `Person.age`?

```
>>>from collections import namedtuple
>>>Person = namedtuple('Person', ['age', 'name'])
>>>bob = Person('20', 'bob')
>>>jim = Person('20', 'jim')
>>>bob < jim
True
```

Comment: `namedtuple` objects *are `tuple` objects*. Tuples are compared lexicographically.

Comment: I believe from `('20', 'bob') < ('20', 'jim')`, you can see the corresponding elements in the tuples are lexicographically compared.

Comment: @roganjosh yeah, but that seems like it should simply be another question, and regardless, how to implement comparisons in Python is *also* a duplicate. Feel free to vote to re-open. It's a democracy in that regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's using string comparison, just concatenating the values:

```
>>> Person = namedtuple('Person', ['age', 'name'])
>>> bob = Person('20', 'bob')
>>> jim = Person('20', 'jim')
>>> bob < jim
True
>>> bob = Person('20', 'jin')
>>> bob < jim
False
>>> bob = Person('20', 'jim')
>>> bob < jim
False
>>> bob = Person('21', 'jim')
>>> bob < jim
False
>>> bob = Person('19', 'jim')
>>> bob < jim
True
```

Comment: The items in a tuple can be any object, not just strings.  Named tuples are tuples and inherit tuple comparison.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
from collections import namedtuple

class Person(namedtuple('Person', ['age', 'name'])):
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.age > other.age

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.age < other.age

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.age == other.age
```

However, does it really make sense for a `Person` to be less than or greater than by age? Why not explicitly check `Person.age`?

Comment: I advise against this, generally, a subclass should behave like it's super class, i.e. it is a specialization, but any property of the parent class should also hold for the child class. In this case, the child-class is behaving differently for comparisons. Probably just better to make an entirely separate classs that doesn't derive from `namedtuple`, or as you say, just be explicit and compare the ages...